# Probability of getting a bingo on the Nth turn

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, problem-solving

I'm trying to do what the title says, and I've figured it out for 4 and 5 terms, checking my answers with [this database](https://wizardofodds.com/games/bingo/probabilities/1/) but when I try 6 I get over double the correct answer. The rules are standard american rules, 75 numbers, free space in the middle, and the B column can have numbers 1-15, I can have 16-30, and so on.

For 4 terms the formula I derived was $$ \frac{{16*3*2*1}}{\frac{75!}{71!}} $$
The 16 came from the 16 possible squares the first number could be in, 3 is the squares the second number can be in, because once you know the first number, you know what has to be your bingo, and then 2 and 1 for the last two numbers. This gives the correct answer of 1.69 x 10^-6.

Getting bingo on the 5th term I used the formula $$ (\frac{{16*3*2*1}}{\frac{75!}{71!}})*4 + (\frac{{16*8*3*2*1}}{\frac{75!}{70!}}) + (\frac{{8*4*3*2*1}}{\frac{75!}{70!}}) $$
The first term is the same as the previous, except I multiplied it by 4, because since there is 5 numbers total now, one number could be anything not including the 4 in the final solution. Therefore there would be 4 different ways to put in the extra number. The extra number cannot go at the end, or else that would mean that they won in 4 turns.
The second term represents the probability of getting a 5 in a row, not including when the BINGO starts on a value in the center cross-section. There are 16 possible initial squares, after selecting a cell, there are now 2 rows that can be picked, the horizontal row, or the vertical row. Therefore there are now 8 new cells that will still give possibility to getting a BINGO. After the second number is selected, there are now 3 possible numbers left to choose, so 3 x 2 x 1.
The third term represents the probability of getting a 5 in a row when the first value is in the center cross-section. There are 8 cells that fit this criteria, after 1 is selected, there are 4 cells left, then 3 x 2 x 1.
This gives the correct answer, which is 1.69 x 10^-5.

Now the problem appears. My logic for the next step is the same formula, except now since there are 6 numbers I multiply all the terms by 5, since there is now the same ways of getting 5 in a row, but now there is an extra number. The extra number can go in any order but the last, giving 5 slots it can go into. However, this answer is wrong, but I don't understand what's wrong with my reasoning.

If something didn't make sense please let me know,
Thanks

Edit: Here's a picture of a bingo board. By center cross section I mean the "N" column and the third row.

[image: Bingo Board]

Comment: Could you explain the rules in more detail for those of us who don't play bingo, please?  How many square are on the card?  What do you mean by the "center cross section"?

Comment: Yeah sorry, the board is a 5x5 with a free space in the center, meaning that spot is already claimed. The center cross section is the 3rd row and 3rd column. I added a picture for clarity.